# How to access the internal value of a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following nested dictionary,

```
Data = [{'seriesId': 'Food and Beverage',
  'forecastPoint': '2020-08-26T00:00:00Z',
  'rowId': 35,
  'timestamp': '2020-08-27T00:00:00.000000Z',
  'predictionValues': [{'value': 32.5133330947, 'label': 'Volume (actual)'}],
  'forecastDistance': 1,
  'prediction': 32.5133330947},
 {'seriesId': 'Food and Beverage',
  'forecastPoint': '2020-08-26T00:00:00Z',
  'rowId': 36,
  'timestamp': '2020-08-28T00:00:00.000000Z',
  'predictionValues': [{'value': 30.2438893873, 'label': 'Volume (actual)'}],
  'forecastDistance': 2,
  'prediction': 30.2438893873}]
```

However I want to bring that dictionary into following form dictionary where I only want to access the `value` from `predictionValues` and get other keys as it is.

Expected output should be a dictionary

```
Data = [{'seriesId': 'Food and Beverage',
  'forecastPoint': '2020-08-26T00:00:00Z',
  'rowId': 35,
  'timestamp': '2020-08-27T00:00:00.000000Z',
  'value': 32.5133330947,
  'forecastDistance': 1,
  'prediction': 32.5133330947},
 {'seriesId': 'Food and Beverage',
  'forecastPoint': '2020-08-26T00:00:00Z',
  'rowId': 36,
  'timestamp': '2020-08-28T00:00:00.000000Z',
  'value': 30.2438893873,
  'forecastDistance': 2,
  'prediction': 30.2438893873}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
for i in range(len(Data)):
    Data[i]['predictionValues'] = Data[i]['predictionValues'][0]['value']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for d in Data:
    d.update({'value': d.pop('predictionValues')[0].pop('value')})
```

Answer (score 0):

The original list of dictionaries seems to contain the prediction value already, so just deleting the predictionValue entry should do the trick

```
for dictionary in Data:
    del dictionary['predictionValues']
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a play on list comprehension with `dict` :

```
[
    dict( (key, value)
          if not isinstance(value, list)
          else ("value", entry[key][0]["value"])
          for key, value in entry.items()
         )
        for entry in Data
]

[{'seriesId': 'Food and Beverage',
  'forecastPoint': '2020-08-26T00:00:00Z',
  'rowId': 35,
  'timestamp': '2020-08-27T00:00:00.000000Z',
  'value': 32.5133330947,
  'forecastDistance': 1,
  'prediction': 32.5133330947},
 {'seriesId': 'Food and Beverage',
  'forecastPoint': '2020-08-26T00:00:00Z',
  'rowId': 36,
  'timestamp': '2020-08-28T00:00:00.000000Z',
  'value': 30.2438893873,
  'forecastDistance': 2,
  'prediction': 30.2438893873}]
```